# What class to use for downloading big file size (4.7GB) using ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a controller dedicated for download files which looks like:

```
  public ActionResult Download( string ids )
  {

     MyFileModel myfile = new MyFileModel(ids);
     Stream s = myfile.GetStream();

     return File( s, contentType, newFileName );
  }
```

I saw that `File` from return is `FileStreamResult` but my RAM becomes full (i have 8GB and download raeches 7GB) and CPU 100%

How to optimize the download ?

Comment: What is the type of `fileModel` ?

Comment: `MyFileModel` type which extends `FileModel`, I've added `GetStream()` function which returns `Stream` object. But I will move my mind to Darin suggestion.

Comment: I updated my code by replacing `...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How to optimize the download ?

Do not load the entire file in memory. Keep it on the disk and specify the location to this file on the server as first argument to the File method:

```
// get the physical location of the file on the disk:
string file = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/somefile.dat");
return File(file, contentType, newFileName );
```

Now if you tell me that you stored a 5GB file inside your database, well, what do you expect me to tell you? I think you already know the answer.

But as @Marc stated in the comments section even if you stored such huge file in your database you could still implement this efficiently. The idea is to write a custom ActionResult which will read the file in chunks from the database stream and flush those chunks directly to the Response OutputStream.

Comment: Re your last line: you can stream from databases; I'm not saying it is the perfect solution, but it is perfectly doable - either by using a forwards-only data-reader as part of a custom `ActionResult`, or by using the FILESTREAM support

Comment: Yes, that's true. Async ADO.NET would allow you to efficiently achieve that.

Comment: works fine pre-async too; just loop using a buffer that is multiples of 8040 bytes

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: you suggest to put only the path to file instead of Stream, right ?

Comment: @SnakeEyes it isn't clear in your scenario what overload you are calling: is `fileModel` a `byte[]`? a `Stream`? a `string`? all of those are valid overloads of `return File(...)`

Comment: I answered to your above question. I put stream inside `File` not fileModel...my mistake

Comment: @SnakeEyes, that's alright, but you seem to be calling some `GetStream()` method on your model. It will hugely depend on the implementation of this method. If you already have a `byte[]` property on your model holding the entire file and the `GetStream()` is simply copying this byte array to a MemoryStream I hope you realize that it would be a complete waste. If you want to really optimize this, you should never load the entire file in-memory (byte array). You should read the underlying Stream from the database (or wherever it is stored) and write to the response output stream in chunks.

Comment: Basically you should be reading the file in chunks from the network socket with your database and write it to the network socket of the output response in chunks.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov : Can you please give us an example/link on how to write the chunks in network socket?

Comment: @abcdefghi, sure, just use the [`Stream.CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto.aspx) method to copy from your database TCP stream to the response output stream.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov : Thanks. `Copy to` will replace the current fetched db chunk stream with the destination chunk stream. As you stated the suggestion that it should be received in chunks. Question - How will it persist the previous chunk? or How can I append the stream chunks received from the database?

Comment: There's no need to persist anything in memory. Both are network sockets. The CopyTo method reads from the source string some byte array chunk and writes it to the destination stream. But since both are NetworkStreams you really should not care about loading anything in memory.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov : I am sorry, I did not get your point. I meant to say that let's I started receiving the first chunk and received it successfully. Next time I will definitely start after the endpoint of chunk 1. I meant let's say the counting is from 1 to 1000. I started to receive 1-100 and received successfully. Next time I will start from 101-200. right? Question - Where will I keep the stream starts from 1-100? In some variable ? and once the chunk 101-200 is received...will i append it with 1-100 chunk part ?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the whole point. You don't need to be storing anything. You should get a Stream from your database pointing to the column containing the file or if you are using the FILESTREAM type you will directly get such stream. Then simply call the `CopyTo` method on this stream to the `Response.OutputStream`. The CopyTo method internally reads the source stream in chunks of 80KB and writes them to the destination stream. The problem might be if you are using an ORM such as Entity Framework which already maps to some byte array the column. Then you are busted.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov : Kindly confirm my understanding. Let me summarize my understanding. Example the stream is stored in the database. `Execute scalar ADO.Net function` will fetch the column value for a particular row. return the scalar value(stream) to presentation layer. Finally write the following code in your Action method `System.IO.Stream s = GetStreamFromDb(1); return new FileStreamResult(s.CopyTo(Response.OutputStream), "image/jpg");`

Comment: Your understanding is almost correct. I would write a custom action result (instead of using `FileStreamResult`) which will take the source stream as constructor parameter and perform the CopyTo in the implementation. Then from the controller action I would simply `return new MyActionResult(GetStreamFromDb(1));`.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - sir, this is my Last Question - Kindly confirm this point. **Stream.CopyTo** - `The CopyTo method reads from the source string some byte array chunk and writes it to the destination stream`. Is there any way to declare the chunk size? or it is decided by the Framework at runtime ?

Comment: Yes, there is a way, just use [`the overload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783870.aspx) which takes the chunk size as second parameter.